# Get object keys for properties having non-empty array as a value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array:

```
417: Array(2)
0: 24301
1: 24300
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
418: [24562]
length: 419
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Now, i need to get all those keys from this array `arr` whose length is greater than 0. In this case, i need the answer as `['417','418']`.

I have tried to filter using `each` loop and `.length` of each element as:

My code is as:

```
        console.log(arr_of_sel_units);
        $.each(arr_of_sel_units, function(k, v) {
            console.log(v.length)
        });
```

But, it is returning error `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

Comment: Try `let arr = {};`

Comment: Named array properties is not a good idea, use `Object` type for `arr`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If proper datatype (`Object`) used for `arr`, you may do `Array.prototype.filter()` across `Object.keys()` (however, it will work for your notation just as well as array is essentially an object):

```js
const src = {a: ['1','2','3' ], b: [], c: ['1' ], d: []},

      result = Object.keys(src).filter(key => src[key].length)
      
console.log(result)
```

Comment: actually i have updated with the exact question, could you please look at it again. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: I got your suggestion. Howver, could you suggest me how could I push these values for `        let arr_of_sel_units = [];
        $.each(buildings_arr, function(item,v){
            arr_of_sel_units[v]=[];
        });`

Comment: @AayushDahal : exactly because of improper data type you cannot use `$.each()` to iterate over your source data structure as `$.each()` [expects](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/#jQuery-each-object-callback) either array (and iterates ***only*** over its items, ignoring named properties) or object as a parameter, but not object-like array. You may find short snippet that demonstrates my point [over here](https://codepen.io/ygorbunkov/pen/qBZEBaG?editors=0012).

Answer (score 0):

Use `Object.entries`, `filter`

```js
let arr = [];
arr["a"] = ["1", "2", "3"];
arr["b"] = [];
arr["c"] = ["1"];
arr["d"] = [];

const res = Object.entries(arr)
  .filter(([, value]) => value.length > 0)
  .map(([key]) => key);

console.log(res);
```